# Same Ionic Framework interface for Mobile and non-mobile browsers?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on 2 identical GUI: 1 for mobile (using Ionic), 1 for non-mobile. The non-mobile interface is responsive so it's already mobile-ready! So, 99% of the code is the same.

I develop the mobile part of the GUI in Ionic Framework (Angular). The non-mobile interface is using Angular only. I could simply merge the non-mobile site (Angular only) into the Ionic project. Then, I would only have ONE branch to maintain.

Knowing that we can use the command "ionic serve" to expose the Ionic Interface in the non-mobile browser, I am thinking to simply use the command "ionic serve" on the production server to expose the web interface of the ionic to non-mobile users. Is it a good practice? If not, what should I do to have 1 branch only?

Comment: you can have 100% of the same code (except for cordova plugins of course) just drop your www folder on a node/express server and serve the files, you have a identical mobile app and webpage. All ionic serve effectively does is open you index.htlm in a browser.

Comment: Yeah your www folder is literally just a webpage. When you do the build is when all the magic happens and turns it into a app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing ionic serve is creating a webserver on your folder `www`

This will not perform many very usefull operation for production such as :

- minification / offuscation
- clearing comments
- sass build etc...

Those tasks are for example triggered by `grunt / gulp` tasks or `hooks` into `ionic build` command if your properly configure it.

Therefore, I'd recommand you the two possibilities :

1. cordova platform add browser

This is the one I prefer, as you can take good advange of cordova hooks steps and use the same hooks for mobile & non mobile.

2. Copy your www folder and make your own build process

In both case, you'll have to perform some tests as ionic is developped and optimized for Android & iOS, which is not all mobiles (ex: windows phones ) and not browsers. 
I remember on one project adding some spec class for browser and detecting if user uses browser or not for specific behaviours.

Comment: With possibility 1 you propose, I would keep my Angular Project and just add a Cordova plugin to it, right? I already have the Angular Project with a very detailed gulp file. So in the same folder, I could build my ionic project that uses the same files as the Angular project... In my Angular project folder, I would just install Ionic to it?  npm install -g cordova ionic